# How can I get a decimal result into a SQL Server table when dividing two integers?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is what I am currently doing:

```
CREATE TABLE #compareDiffs
(
    groupAPercentDifference DECIMAL
)

DECLARE @groupaprev AS int
DECLARE @groupacurr AS int

SET @groupaprev = 144
SET @groupacurr = 114

INSERT INTO #compareDiffs
    SELECT (@groupaprev - @groupacurr) / CAST(@groupaprev AS DECIMAL (7,2))

--Select #1
SELECT * FROM #compareDiffs

--Select #2
SELECT (@groupaprev - @groupacurr) / CAST(@groupaprev AS DECIMAL (7,2))

groupAPercentDifference
0

(No column name)
0.20833333
```

Select #1 (the value in the table) always returns 0.
Select #2 (straight evaluation) returns .20833333 which is what I want in the table.

This looks straightforward but I must be missing a conversion somewhere. Can anyone assist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Gordon's answer. A `DECIMAL` declaration without precision and scale defined defaults to `DECIMAL(18,0)`, which is basically an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE #compareDiffs (
    groupAPercentDifference DECIMAL
);
```

Defines a column with a *scale* of `0` and a default precision of `18` -- no digits after the decimal, 18 digits before.  I would suggest something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #compareDiffs (
    groupAPercentDifference DECIMAL(10, 4)
);
```

But perhaps you want a floating point representation.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  I think you have helped me before.  That fixed it.

Comment: @SteveCross: if this answer helped you solve your problem, please **accept** it and thus show the person providing the answer your gratitude. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)

Comment: Sorry to take so long.  I overlooked it as pending.  This solution did work for me.  Thank you Mr. Linoff.